# Collecting java stream matters if underlying stream is parallel or not

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following function:

```
public Stream getStream(boolean isParallel) {

...
return someSteamFromHere;
}
```

This function will return a parallel stream if "isParallel" is true, otherwise a sequential stream. Now I want to collect this parallel/sequential stream. Does the caller function need to implement this logic:

```
boolean isParallel = isParallel();
Stream stream = getStream(isParallel);
List list;
if (isParallel) {
   list = stream.parallel().collect(Collectors.toList());
} else {
   list = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Or can i simply collect the stream regardless, and if its parallel, it will be collected in parallel and if sequential, it will be collected in a single thread?

Comment: Do you care about the order in the resulting list?

Comment: If `getStream` is correctly returning a parallel stream if `isParallel` is true, then the caller doesn't need to duplicate that logic.

Comment: The order doesn't matter @Eritrean.

Comment: @LouisWasserman .. Thanks. Will remove the duplicate logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

parallelism is a property of the stream. So, if you have a parallel stream, calling `.parallel()` on this is a no-op. It does absolutely nothing whatsoever.

Note that collecting a parallel stream does imply that any concept of 'order' is right out the window.

Your code can just be `List list = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());`.

Note that as a general rule, if parallelism matters at all, collecting it into a list seems... bizarre. Whatever performance benefits you think you're getting from treating it parallel are pretty much obliterated when you do this.

Comment: Why would you say the performance benefits are obliterated?  If the intermediary operations are expensive, they'll still be parallelized.

Comment: But the code as shown doesn't do any operations on stream elements at all, other than collect them.

Comment: I am doing the intermediate operations lazily and want to perform them in parallel and then operate on the resulting list in sequential manner in a single thread. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you pass in the boolean to the function if you use it after the function's return? Either the function receives the boolean and uses it or it doesn't get it and the test sits outside as you wrote.
Btw, functions with boolean parameters are considered code smell as they clearly do more than one thing. Have a look [here](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1392524).

Comment: The passing the boolean was just for an example to explain what i am trying to do. The actual code works differently.